# IE 10 Copy/ Paste issue

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

The copy and paste functionality is not working for me in IE 10 I tried to copy some data from  notepad to text area in the browser it is not showing the data in the text area.

Comment: Is that happen at your asp.net site only or it's a general issue with all websites? Check it this solution might help http://www.favbrowser.com/internet-explorer-10-copy-paste-no-longer-works/

Comment: I tried with the link that didn't help

Comment: Is that happen at your asp.net site only?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but I also ran into issues with clipboard in IE.

First of all `paste` event doesn't work, you should use `beforepaste`.
The `ClipboardEvent` does not exist, the `DragEvent` it's used instead and to get `clipboardData` you access it from `window` not from the event object.

But even so, it doesn't seem to work to access in JavaScript the files/images copied into clipboard.

In the end, Clipboard API doesn't seem to be supported in IE: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/clipboardapi/